# Which European countries still allow Russian government bonds to be sold on their markets?

Tags: russian-federation, sanctions, central-bank

According to [NBC](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/russia-sanctions-are-big-deal-experts-say-effects-take-years-rcna17380), Russia is not able to sell government bonds in the US and some European countries, after invading Ukraine:

> Tuesday’s sanctions also barred the Russian Central Bank from
> financing in the U.S. and **some European countries**, meaning Russian
> government bonds can no longer be sold in many Western markets,
> causing their values to plummet.

I am wondering about which actual European countries still allow Russian government bonds. This is particularly interesting since [virtually all EU countries seem to favor SWIFT disconnection](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/momentum-grows-ban-russia-swift-payment-system-2022-02-26/).

Comment: For clarification, by European countries you mean EU countries, as there are still European countries which are not EU members.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is about European countries and not explecitly EU countries then Serbia is one of the countries, that has imposed no oficial sanctions on Russia. So theoreticaly Russia should still be alowed to sell government bonds in Serbia. Since Turkey is EU candidate it can be seen as another country not having imposed any oficial sanctions on Russia.